# How to remove specific values in a multi level numpy array given matrix of indices

Tags: python, numpy

suppose `x = np.array([[30,60,70],[100,20,80]])` and i wish to remove all elements that are `<60`. That is, the resulting array should be `x = np.array([[60,70],[100,80]])`.

I use `x = np.array([[30,60,70],[100,20,80]])` to find the indices of the needed elements. And I get `indices = (array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]))`. However, when I am trying to delete the elements in `x` via `np.delete(x, indices)`, i get `array([ 70, 100,  20,  80])` rather than what i was hoping.

What can I do to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np


x = np.array([[30, 60, 70],
              [100, 20, 80]])


new_x = np.array([(np.delete(i, np.where(i < 60)[0])) for i in x])

print(new_x)
```

Got it this way but idk if works too slow for large arrays

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np 

d = np.array([
    [30,60,70],
    [100, 20, 80]
])

f = lambda x: x > 60
a = np.array([a[f(a)] for a in d])
print(a)
```

Comment: The OP is specifically asking a solution for numpy arrays, not lists.

Comment: @alec_djinn changed to numpy arrray

Comment: It is still returning a list. Aside from that, I think the OP is looking for an array method rather than using a for-loop. That is why most people use numpy in the first place, to avoid loops on numeric arrays.